# azure function pipeline automate setup

Tags: azure, function, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

can we automatically create a pipeline for each new function thats created ie fully automate the lot? Im not sure if it possible and wondering if anyone has done or can point me to something that has a set by step pocess?

Comment: You mean creating the Az Functions using eg ARM or Bicep?

Comment: i can set up the azure function with bicep template or manually create one but was wondering that after one is created, is there a way that it can automatically create a pipeline for it? I'm sure that a certain pipeline needs to be created first but you could use it with any other new function app that is created that would create a pipeline for it?

Answer (score 0):

> can we automatically create a pipeline for each new function thats
> created ie fully automate the lot?

Yes, you can.

For the simplest situation, for example, this is the deployment pipeline on my side:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
parameters:
  - name: functionname
    default: bowman0822
steps:
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: 'xxx'
    pipeline: 'xxx'
    buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
    downloadType: 'single'
    downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
- script: |
    dir
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
- task: AzureFunctionApp@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'testbowman_in_AAD'
    appType: 'functionAppLinux'
    appName: '${{parameters.functionname}}'
    package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/azurefunction'
    runtimeStack: 'PYTHON|3.9'

#key step see the below.
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
      import requests
      import json
      
      org_name = "<The Organization Name>"
      project_name = "<The Product Name>"
      pipeline_name = "${{parameters.functionname}}"
      pat = "<Your Personal Access Token>"
      
      url = "https://dev.azure.com/"+org_name+"/"+project_name+"/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=5.0"
      
      payload = json.dumps({
        "name": ""+pipeline_name+"",
        "Repository": {
          "name": "functiontest",
          "type": "TfsGit"
        },
        "Process": {
          "phases": [
            {
              "name": "Agent job 1",
              "refName": "Job_1",
              "condition": "succeeded()",
              "target": {
                "executionOptions": {
                  "type": 0
                },
                "allowScriptsAuthAccessOption": False,
                "type": 1
              },
              "jobAuthorizationScope": "project"
            }
          ]
        }
      })
      headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Basic '+pat,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
      
      response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
      
      print(response.text)
```

Successfully created on my side:

[image]

Please note that the above sample is the simplest situation, there is nothing in the created pipeline. If you want specific requirements in pipeline, I suggest you to first manually create a pipeline, and then use [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) so that from the response you can know how the request structure of Create API should be.

The code above is based on this REST API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

By the way, if you want YAML definition, there should be additional step to push the YAML definition to your repo.

Comment: @DarraghM Hi DarraghM, any update on this issue, have your check my answer? does it answer your question?

Comment: I will be looking to set it up today or tomorrow so will report back then

Comment: @DarraghM Hi DarraghM, any update?